# Div Moves During Hover Animation in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

**DESCRIPTION**

I have a button div that css flips on hover. It wasn't working on IE due to them not recognizing preserve3D. So I updated my code and it works, but I have a problem.

**PROBLEM**

When I hover over it in Internet Explorer 11, it moves down and to the left slightly during the flip. By "slightly", I mean a pixel down and a pixel to the left - ONLY during the hover animation. No hover - normal. Hover on - moves during animation. Hover off - normal after animation is done.
Any idea why?

**NOTE**

It stays put on Chrome 49 and Firefox 45 as intended.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<p>This moves down and left during hover animation on Internet Explorer 11.<br> Stays put in Chrome 49 and Firefox 45.</p>
<div class="downloadButtonFullContainer">
    <div class="downloadButtonFull">
        <div class="downloadButtonFullFront">
            <div class="downloadButtonFullFrontImage"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="downloadButtonFullBack">
            <a href="#" title="view or download" target="_blank ">
                <div class="downloadButtonFullBackImage"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODEPEN**

[codepen](http://codepen.io/zuhloobie/pen/qZXYvv)

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't know why (do we really still ask that question, when it comes to IE ...?) - but have you tried countering the effect by offsetting the element one pixel up and one pixel to the right when hovered? (If that works, use a CSS hack that targets the relevant IE versions, or something like that.) Btw., terrible class names :) - I mean, even include specific pixel dimension _in_ the class name? (Never even mind the unnecessary repetition, like specifying the same width and height for both `.downloadButton82pxFrontImage` and `.downloadButton82pxBackImage` in separate rules ...)

Comment: I understand your point about width/height. As far as names, I have the same button on other pages in other sizes and prefer to specify that in the class name. Good or bad, it's how my brain works :/ I'll look into hacking it with an offset. Thanks.

Comment: If at any point in the future the button width has to change for any reason - and even if it was just about one pixel - then you'll either have to modify your HTML code everywhere that class is used; or you don't change the class in the HTML, but only the value in the CSS rule, so that you end up with a "lying" class name - that's not really maintenance friendly. A class name should rather describe what an element's meaning/function is, rather than what it is _currently_ supposed to look like.

Comment: I completely understand that and I appreciate your input, but in this particular case, these will absolutely, without a doubt, never change so there is more value in the class name being specific. Thanks again.

Comment: @CBroe - After more thought, I am able to do as you suggest with the class names. Thanks for keeping me straight.